# SerialDevice.LoadAsync block await task

Tags: c#, serial-port, windowsiot

I having a little issue reading data from Nave32 Flight Controller, I'm able to send data to the card using the SerialDevice class but when the LoadAsync Method is call and there is no more data to read the app hung and does not move forward, there is not exception during the execution of the process. I look at the app state and there is a bunch a task block and I'm not sure why. See image below

**UPDATE**

Firmware source code is [here](https://github.com/multiwii)

here is my example code

```
namespace Apps.Receiver
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.dataRecived.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

        private async Task readAsync(SerialDevice serialPort)
        {
            string data = string.Empty;
            using (var dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream))
            {
                try
                {
                    dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.None;
                    var hasData = true;
                    while (hasData)
                    {

                        var bytesRead = await dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(serialPort.DataBits);
                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                            data += dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
                        else
                            hasData = false;


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    status.Text = "reading data fail: " + ex.Message;
                    closeDevice(serialPort);
                }
            }

            dataRecived.Text = data;
        }

        private async void sendData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var serialPort = await getSerialDevice("COM3");

            if (dataToSend.Text.Length != 0)
            {

                using (var dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (dataToSend.Text.Equals("#", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                            dataWriteObject.WriteString(dataToSend.Text);
                        else
                            dataWriteObject.WriteString(dataToSend.Text + "\n");

                        var bytesWritten = await dataWriteObject.StoreAsync();
                        if (bytesWritten > 0)
                        {
                            status.Text = dataToSend.Text + ", ";
                            status.Text += "bytes written successfully!";
                        }
                        await readAsync(serialPort);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        status.Text = "writing data fail: " + ex.Message;
                    }
                }
                closeDevice(serialPort);
            }
            else
            {
                status.Text = "Enter the text you want to write and then click on 'WRITE'";
            }
        }

        private void closeDevice(SerialDevice device)
        {
            device.Dispose();
            device = null;
        }

        private async Task<SerialDevice> getSerialDevice(string portName)
        {
            var aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM3");
            var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

            if (devices.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("Unablet to connect to device");

            var serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(devices[0].Id);

            if (serialPort == null)
                throw new Exception("Unablet to Open to port " + portName);


            serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;

            return serialPort;
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

See this example, try if it helps doing it like this:

```
await reader.LoadAsync(8192);   
while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)   
{   
    strBuilder.Append(reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength));   
    await reader.LoadAsync(8192);   
}
```